# Where can I get CloudVPN? It's installed on all my servers but I can barely find any info about it

Tags: linux, vpn

I recently became responsible for looking after a group of servers, and am now trying to add a new one.  The existing servers all have CloudVPN running, but I can find almost no information about it.  Does anyone know where it is available, or what a good alternative would be (that would not require any/much downtime)?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe have a look at wikipedia regarding CloudVPN (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloudvpn).

If you need some VPN solution you can use *OpenVPN* (http://openvpn.net/)

Comment: The wiki page says the project was last updated 4 years ago, and links to an external page which does not exist any more.  That (and a lot of other searching) is why I said "I can find almost no information".

Comment: IMHO it's time to change your vpn solution and give OpenVPN a chance. Have you seen the Link from wikipedia? If yes... have you done some research on the site? -> http://repos.e-x-a.org/view.cgi/cloudvpn/

Comment: Yes, I am ready to change - but only if I have to - I don't want to take the whole website offline while re-configuring the VPN if it is not necessary.  I did not see that specific page on e-x-a.org - I only saw either commentary, or links that did not work, so thank you for that.  Is OpenVPN what people really use?  At a minimum of $60/year?  I only need to connect the servers to each other, not tunnel into them privately.